# JavaScript - how to assign onclick efficiently in template literals

Tags: javascript, templates, literals

I want to add piece of html using template literals on page from my extension. The page can be anything, it is not mine, I cannot control naming conventions. How do I efficiently assign events for elements in my template?

- I cannot use ID because such ID may already exists on page.
- When I use class with nice name (e.g. "delete" or "send") it may already be used on page
- When I find it like n-th button I would have to update index number every time I refactor template (e.g. changing [2] to [3] when I add new button) - div.getElementsByTagName('button')[2].onclick = function () {...};
- Right now I use class with very_long_unique_prefix_delete, very_long_unique_prefix_send, ...

I'm looking for a better way?

Comment: Are the elements in some kind of container? If so `container.querySelector("#id")` will always work.

Comment: id must be unique, if I use logical name like "menu" it will probably already exists on page